# If f:X→R is a continuous non constant function and X is connected then X is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous non constant function and $(X,d)$ is a connected metric space then $X$ is uncountable.

How to proceed this proof I am clueless , I know that if $X$ is connected so $f(X)$ is also connected and $f$ is non constant to $f(X)$ is an interval which is not singleton, also each interval is uncountable, so, $f(X)$ is uncountable does it means that $X$ is also uncountable? Any other methods other than this to understand this question?

Comment: Yes, if $f(X)$ is uncountable, then so is $X$. Think about it: How many points in $X$ do you need at least to hit $\lvert f(X) \rvert$ different points in $ℝ$ via $f$?